# Itreid Create table with Latex with split columns and rows

Tags: tables, tabularx, multicolumn

Can you please help me creating the following table in latex. I would be very grateful if the first column (Percentage of Cumulative probability) appears exactly as in the table. Moreover, Is it possible to make it span the two columns in a paper?

Many thanks

[image]

I tried this so far which is not compltelty waht I want to do but this what I could do:

```
\begin{table*}[ht]

\begin{tabular}{| l | l | c | c | c | c |}

  \hline

  \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{Percentage of Cumulative probability}    & Title & Location Error (m)& Expected Improvement  \\

  \hline

\multirow{2}{*}{50$\%$}&Here\\ &Here & 214 & text\\ 

  \hline

  \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{67$\%$}     & text & text   & text \\

  \hline

    \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{95$\%$}     & text & text   & text \\

  \hline

\end{tabular}

\end{table*}
```

Comment: Please show what you tried so far.

Comment: Some hint: `table*` instead of `table` tow make the table span both columns, `\multirow` for the vertically centered contents of the first and last column and the `booktabs` package for the horizontal lines. If the text in teh second column is quite long, `tabularx` might also be useful. For the column headers, `\thead` from the `makecell` package might be useful.

Comment: Please tell us which document class you employ.

Comment: \documentclass[11pt,twocolumn,a4paper]{article}

Comment: What did you try already? Please tell us what part of the table is specifically problematic to achieve. A small compilable example that shows what you achieved so far would be extremely helpful.

Comment: \begin{table*}[ht]
\begin{tabular}{| l | l | c | c | c | c |}
  \hline
  \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{Percentage of Cumulative probability}    & Title & Location Error (m)& Expected Improvement  \\
  \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{50$\%$}&SADOA\\ &Proposed & 214 & text\\ 
  \hline
  \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{67$\%$}     & text & text   & text \\
  \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{95$\%$}     & text & text   & text \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table*}

Comment: Could you please add the code directly into your question? You can use the edit button on the left bottom of your question to add this information there.

Comment: Please also clarify the desired output. In your question you show a table without vertical lines, your example code has a lot of them. Also, which column does "SADOA"  and "Proposed"  belong to? Also, your code contains 6 columns, while the table in your question only seems to contain 4?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I don't need these vertical lines but I am not sure how to reach to the desired result which is the picture in the question. Alos, I removed SADOA and Proposed from the code. They are just "Here" words nowThanks for your help again.

Comment: @AliA.: Sure, but in which column do the two "Here"  belong? In the right half of "Percentage of...", in the "title"  column, ...?

Comment: You can take a picture as a reference and give me the solution for title and one row of results and I will continue from there. Thanks!

Comment: @leandriis  The words belong under the Title column. Every percentage has two possibilities, "Here" and "Here".

Comment: Ok, that makes sense mow. I was confused by the `\multicolumn` commands since there were no merged columns in our table, only merged rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sill not sure, if I understood your request correctly, but here are two suggestions under the assumption that "Here"  in the "title"  column actually is some longer text.

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\itshape}
\begin{document}


\begin{table*}
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lXcc}
    \toprule
    \thead[l]{Percentage of\\ cumulative probability}
      & \thead[l]{Title}
        & \thead{Location error\\ for (metres)}
         & \thead{Expected\\ improvement}\\
    \midrule
    \multirow{2}{*}{50\%}
      & Here 
        & 214 
          & \multirow{2}{*}{No.} \\
      & Here
        & 110 \\
    \midrule
  \end{tabularx}
\end{table*}

\begin{table}
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{lXcc}
    \toprule
    \thead[l]{Percentage of\\ cumulative\\ probability}
      & \thead[l]{Title}
        & \thead{Location\\ error for\\ (metres)}
         & \thead{Expected\\ improvement}\\
    \midrule
    \multirow{2}{*}{50\%}
      & Here 
        & 214 
          & \multirow{2}{*}{No.} \\
      & Here
        & 110 \\
    \midrule
  \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much.. :) I t worked perfectly. Can I ask for one more favor please. If want to add vertical lines between the four columns, What should I do?

Comment: I wuld not recomment adding vertical lines. They make table look less appealing. If you however wat to add them, replace `\toprule`, `\midrule` and `\bottomrule` with `\hlne, remove the `booktabs` package from your preamble and add `|` where you want a vertical line (For example `{lXc|c}` for a vertical line between the third and last column.)

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind response. I will take by your recommendation, though.. :)